# Air for Android - Undefined property EncryptedLocalStore

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm building an *AIR 2.5* app with *Adobe Flash CS5*. By publishing it for *Air for Android* 
I got this error:

```
1120: Access of undefined property EncryptedLocalStore.
```

This is my code:

```
function saveIt(keybg:String, myvaluebg:String):void
{
var bytesbg:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
      bytesbg.writeUTFBytes(myvaluebg); 
      EncryptedLocalStore.setItem(keybg, bytesbg);
}
```

Do I need to got throw all my code to delete *EncryptedLocalStore* related code or is there a smarter way available?

Can it be that *EncryptedLocalStore* is not supporter for Air for Android?

Thanks.
Uli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EncryptedLocalStore documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/EncryptedLocalStore.html):

- "In addition, this feature is not supported on mobile platforms prior to AIR 3."

Upgrade to AIR 3 or later.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure from your question if this is a runtime, or compile time error, so here goes anyway:

[**Compile Time**]

Is the class in the import statements at the top of the class?

```
import com.adobe.air.crypto.EncryptionKeyGenerator;
```

[**Runtime**]

Are both `keybg`, and `bytesbg` not null values.